# Error in ANDROID with WSDL and ksoap2

Tags: php, android, soap, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I have a problem accessing a web service made ​​in PHP. I tried many codes but do not know if I have a stupid bug that makes me not work.

The Webservice I think is good because if I make the call from a page in PHP works, but if I access via Android does not work, so is the call I make in ANDROID.

The error occurs in: transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,null);

The error is: `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions name='SMB_GestionBoda' targetNamespace='http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl'>@8:43 in java.io.InputStreamReader@405d9f50)`

Thanks.

**The WSDL:**

```
<definitions 
    name='SMB_GestionBoda'
    targetNamespace='http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl'
    xmlns:tns='http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl'
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
    xmlns:soap12='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/'
    xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>   
<message name='GetProvidersRequest'>
    <part name='id_task' type='xsd:int'/>
    <part name='city' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='GetProvidersResponse'>
    <part name='result'/>
</message>
<portType name='SMB_GestionBodaPortType'>
    <operation name='GetProviders'>
        <input message='tns:GetProvidersRequest'/>
        <output message='tns:GetProvidersResponse'/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name='SMB_GestionBodaBinding' type='tns:SMB_GestionBodaPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc'
        transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
    <operation name='GetProviders'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda#GetProviders'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda'
            encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda'
            encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name='SMB_GestionBodaService'>
    <port name='SMB_GestionBodaPort' binding='SMB_GestionBodaBinding'>
        <soap:address location='http://localhost/webservice/GetProviders.php'/>
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**The ANDROID CODE:**

```
//Constantes para la invocacion del web service
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl";
        final String URL="http://192.168.0.10/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetProviders";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda#GetProviders";  

        /*Se crea un objeto SoapObject para poder realizar la peticion
        para consumir el ws SOAP. El constructor recibe
        el namespace. Por lo regular el namespace es el dominio 
        donde se encuentra el web service*/
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("id_task",0);
        request.addProperty("city","valencia");


        /*Se crea un objeto SoapSerializationEnvelope para serealizar la
        peticion SOAP y permitir viajar el mensaje por la nube
        el constructor recibe la version de SOAP*/
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = false; //se asigna true para el caso de que el WS sea de dotNet

        //Se envuelve la peticion soap
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        //Objeto que representa el modelo de transporte
        //Recibe la URL del ws
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        transporte.debug=true;


        try {   
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            //Hace la llamada al ws
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,null);

            //Se crea un objeto SoapPrimitive y se obtiene la respuesta 
            //de la peticion
            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            //result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("MI APP","dump : " + transporte.responseDump);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**The Request DUMP:**

```
<v:Envelope 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<n0:GetProviders id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl">
<id_task i:type="d:int">0</id_task>
<city i:type="d:string">valencia</city>
</n0:GetProviders>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

**The Response DUMP:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions 
    name='SMB_GestionBoda'
    targetNamespace='http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl'
    xmlns:tns='http://localhost/webservice/SMB_GestionBoda.wdsl'
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
    xmlns:soap12='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/'
    xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

<message name='GetProvidersRequest'>
    <part name='id_task' type='xsd:int'/>
    <part name='city' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>
<message name='GetProvidersResponse'>
    <part name='result'/>
</message>

<portType name='SMB_GestionBodaPortType'>
    <operation name='GetProviders'>
        <input message='tns:GetProvidersRequest'/>
        <output message='tns:GetProvidersResponse'/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name='SMB_GestionBodaBinding' type='tns:SMB_GestionBodaPortType'>
    <soap:binding style='rpc'
        transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
    <operation name='GetProviders'>
        <soap:operation soapAction='urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda#GetProviders'/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda'
            encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:localhost-SMB_GestionBoda'
            encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name='SMB_GestionBodaService'>
    <port name='SMB_GestionBodaPort' binding='SMB_GestionBodaBinding'>
        <soap:address location='http://localhost/webservice/GetProviders.php'/>
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL to extension .asmx not .wsdl